# Use of pointers in a division in C99, error: invalid operands to binary

Tags: c, pointers, c99

The question surely look stupid, but I have always wasted a lot of time, with tests/errors until it works, with this kind of problem.

I need a pointer to return a value from a function, then I need to divide this value, but I have the compiler error:

`invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')`

Example in the following code:

```
void test(int *x, int y)
{
    *x = *x+y;
}

int main()
{
    int *x = 20;
    int y = 1;

    test(&x, y);

    printf("x: %i", x);

    float res = x / 2; // error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')

    //float res = *x / 2; // application crash with this one. (GCC native Android)
}
```

I tried with '&' but it didn't work (x = 0), I try cast to int and only get the pointer adress, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mat, I edited the question. Maybe I should change the title if it's only crash with cross compilation?

Comment: `int *x = 20` makes `x` a pointer to address 20, where it is probably not legal to store an `int`.  What were you hoping to accomplish by that?  A pointer needs somewhere to point.  This is invalid code on every platform, though it may work by luck on some.

Comment: It's only to be able to return the value from a larger function.

Comment: with `int *x` you have `x` is a pointer... with `int *x = 20;` you want that pointer to be `20`!??! `20`?? what is at address 20, assuming your computer doesn't barf at making a pointer have that value?

Comment: What does dividing a pointer mean? It's like asking what fish squared is, or half of the sum of all fears.

Comment: I started to understand my mistake... How to declare an int and send it to a function then?

Comment: Did you even check the compiler warnings? `int *x= 20` is initializing a pointer from an int - invalid. `test(&x,y)` calls `test` with the address of x, so with a `int**`, not with a `int*` - invalid. I bet your compiler is warning you. If not, then raise the warning level.

Comment: Problem is I use libraries who throw lot of warning. Sometimes I forget to watch them. Anyway, thx you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you have declared `x` as a pointer to int, but you are trying to use it as an int.  To simply correct the last line, dereference the pointer (just like you've correctly done inside `test()`):

```
float res = *x / 2;
```

Now, it appears you actually tried that and got an error, which is not surprising, because you've initialized `x` badly:

```
int *x = 20;
```

This doesn't create an int value of 20 and make x point to it. It sets x to point at the *memory address* represented by the integer value 20. That's probably reserved memory, which is why you get an error when you try to dereference it.

(You don't get that error in `test()` because you've passed the address of `x` as the argument.  So dereferencing it there actually does get you 20 - probably.)

To make the pointers work, either do:

```
int x = 20;
...
test(&x, y)
...
float res = x / 2;
```

or:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = 20;
...
test(x, y)
..
float res = *x /2;
```

But you are really making this too difficult. Since you only need to output one value from the function, just make the function return that value. Then you have no need to mess about with pointers at all:

```
int test(x,y) { return x+y; }
...
int x = 20;
...
x = test(x,y);
...
float res = x / 2;
```

(And finally, I believe that in any case you want to use `2.0` in the last line, not just `2`, if you want to get a float result instead of an int.)

Comment: Thanks for all those clarifications Dave.

Answer (score 0):

`int * x = 20;` means: `x` is a pointer to an `int` stored at address `20`. When you deference it, the CPU will try to read an `int` value from address `20`, yet address `20` is an invalid address in your current process space and thus your program crashes.

What you probably wanted do say is: `x` is a pointer to an `int` and the value of the `int` it points to is `20`, correct? Well, this would have been:

```
int someInt = 20;
int * x = &someInt;
```

Now `x` points to whatever address `someInt` stores its value (actually it's on the stack space of the main function, but that's just a side node) and the value stored at that address is in fact `20`.